problem with revtex / amsmath.sty
I'm not an expert, just a latex user. My computer uses MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra operating system. One day it was necessary to reinstall TexLive and after that, revtex files that previously compiled with no errors (pdflatex or with TexShop), now do not compile any more. Already looked up for similar problems on the web and nothing; and also installed older versions of MacTeX.pkg; also tried to install TexLive through MacPorts; and the problem persists.
What should I do? Any help, please. Bellow, it is written the compilation error message.
Thank you so much in advance,
Daniel.
amsmath.sty:152: LaTeX Error: Command \negmedspace already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...
l.152 ...egmedspace}{\tmspace-\medmuskip{.2222em}}

Show a small but complete example that errors and its log-file.

some code you have not shown is defining \negmedspace twice, but if you want help finding that you need to show an example

You provided no example but clearly you have an old copy of amsmath.sty
You are getting an "already defined" error on line 152 of  amsmath.sty
l.152 ...egmedspace}{\tmspace-\medmuskip{.2222em}}

But the line setting up \negmedspace in a current amsmath.sty is line 175
\DeclareRobustCommand\negmedspace{\tmspace-\medmuskip{.2222em}}

and this can not give an already defined error as earlier in the file the command is undefined specifically to avoid this error. Line 160 is
\let\negmedspace\@undefined

So if you do have a current tex system installed, check your log file which will show the full path to amsmath.sty. You presumably have a local old or modified version that is masking the amsmath.sty that is in the tex distribution.

Thank you all so much for your help. It's a work around, instead of using revtex I changed to article style
\documentclass[english]{article}
and it went through. I was not able to detect this old version and mask problem. Installed and removed MacTeX.pkg several times, older versions

the log file will give you the exact path to the file causing the problem, you don't need to guess or re-install mactex. @DanielMuller

Hi yes it does, but so I removed the entire folder and tried to reinstall it. I looked into the file, it was amsmath.sty and I did not want to do modifications manually into it.

but where did it say, it was presumably the wrong one, if it showed the path to the standard tex tree, then obviously removing and re-installing will just give you the same file back. But that would mean you are installing an old tex system not a current one. If you had provided an example file and shown the log we would be able to debug, bit you posted no information about the document in your question. @DanielMuller

my computer does not allow to install the up to date version of MacTex

line 175 was different from the one you typed in

what if I install everything from MacPorts? will it do?

@DanielMuller that's fine if you showed an example and showed the log it would say which version you have. I have the git source of amsmath going back 20 years or so, but if you provide no information it's impossible to help.

you really don't need to re-install anything, just putting \let\negmedspace\undefined before amsmath would  make the error go, but I assumed you wanted to fix your installation. @DanielMuller

ooohh if I knew this last thing I would have done that. Now it seems that there is no revtex at all installed, but with the article.sty the amsmath worked through with no problem. We can change to chat. Already thank you so much for your help!
